# Test case execution of Test Link with selenium script

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testlink

I have written a script to automatically run a test case execution of Test Link. I get an error running this script.

I have already given six parameters, and Developer Key and Project name:

```
public class Execution {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String DEVKEY="80851b38d9b92";
    public static String URL="http:///testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php";
    String testProject="MEDFB";
    String testPlan="TP";
    String build="Build";
    String testcase ="MEDFB_BMEAPP-3";
    public static void reportResult(String testProject,String testPlan,String testcase,String build,String Notes,String result) throws TestLinkAPIException{
    TestLinkAPIClient api=new TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY, URL);
    api.reportTestCaseResult(testProject, testPlan, testcase, build, Notes, result= TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED);
}
```

This is `updateTestLinkResult()`:

```
public void updateTestLinkResult(String testCase, String Notes, String result) 
  throws TestLinkAPIException 
{ 
  TestLinkAPIClient testlinkAPIClient = new TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY,URL); 
  testlinkAPIClient.reportTestCaseResult(testProject, testPlan, testcase, build, Notes, result= TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED); 
}
```

This is the test:

```
public void Test1() throws Exception {
  String result = ""; 
  String Notes = "";
  try {
    result= TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED; 
    updateTestLinkResult("TC", null, result); 
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    result = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED; 
    Notes = e.getMessage(); 
    updateTestLinkResult("TC", Notes, result);
  }
```

Error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method reportResult requires 6 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation.
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:198)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:370)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like the framework is automatically loading the test but not finding parameters. Is there additional configuration you haven't included? Also, note that it's probably a bad idea to include things like `DEVKEY` in code you openly post on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have created two instance of `TestLinkAPIClient` one in Class level and in method `updateTestLinkResult()`. Remove it from the class level.
And also in the `updateTestLinkResult()` method, as you are passing the result as parameter why you are hardcoing the result to `result= TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED; remove = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED` it might work.